# Molecule dependency in private gitlab

Tags: ansible, gitlab, molecule

Is there any way how i can resolve dependencies from private project in gitlab? 
On my actual gitlab-ci i use such a trick

requirements.tmpl:

```
- name: my-company.ansible-init-disk
  scm: git
  src: https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.my-company/sre/ansible-roles/ansible-role-init-disk.git
  version: 0.1.0
```

.gitlab-ci.yaml

```
- envsubst < requirements.tmpl > requirements.yaml
- ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yaml -p roles --force-with-deps
```

And voila i got my deps in roles folder.

For molecule i have to do something like

```
dependency:
  name: galaxy
  options:
    role-file: molecule/default/requirements.yml
```

but of cause there is no env interpolation in requirements.yml. see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/36395

Any ideas how to get my deps ?

Comment: I would try using an ssh connection to gitlab with deploy keys if possible. This would remove the need to `envsubst` the requirement file and would work anywhere a recognised ssh key is registered. Regarding gitlab-ci, a solution here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current best solution looks like that

molecule.yml

```
dependency:
  name: shell
  command: $PWD/molecule/default/deps.sh
```

deps.sh

```
envsubst < molecule/default/requirements.tmpl > molecule/default/requirements.yaml
ansible-galaxy install -r molecule/default/requirements.yaml
```

but that look bit ugly